# how to extract text from anchor tag from the string c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have a string :

```
"<a href="/departments/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_test1_Health%20Check‌​%20Assessment.docx">SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docx</a><br><a href="/departments/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_Test2%20W.docx">Tes‌​t2.docx</a><br>"
```

how can i trim it to get only the text:

```
/departments/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_test1_Health%20Check‌​%20Assessment.docx

/departments/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_Test2%20W.docx
```

i just need the text of the URL .

Comment: So you want the `a` tag without `</a>`?

Comment: By using an HTML-parser for instance. You could use a regex for this simple example, but what happens when your `<a>`-tag has more attributes such as `< href= ... class=...>`? In this case regex might get more and more complicated, better use Html-praser, e.g. Agility Pack

Comment: You can use something like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57176/Parsing-HTML-Tags-in-C

Comment: @AlexJolig i edited my question . i just need the text inside those tags

Answer (score 1):

Use RegEx

```
Regex.Matches("yousStringHere" ,@"(?<=href=\")[^>]+(?=\">)")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP3sX8/2)

Comment: I just tried out with @tchelidze answer.It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "<a href="/departments/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_test1_Health%20Check‌​%20Assessment.docx">SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docx</a>"

int start = s.IndexOf("href=") + 5;
int end = s.IndexOf("/"", start);

string result = s.SubString(start, end - start);
```

Without a HTML Parsing Library or RegEx using IndexOf and Substring is the easiest way. *Note: untested, written using iPhone.*

Comment: the value of end will the same as the start, can use `int end = s.IndexOf("/"",start+1);`

Comment: Thanks @Thiru I typed this on my iPhone on train home - otherwise I would have tested it using a debugger